# Post comment with Python

Tags: python, html, post, comments

I would like to post a comment with Python, but I don't really know how to...

here is the html source :

```
<form name="addc" method="post">
  <textarea id="990" name="comments" value=""></textarea>
  <input name="i" value="435" type="hidden">
  <input name="pseudo" value="3454" type="hidden">
  <input name="action" value="Post comment" type="submit">
</form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to write a script to automatically post comments try this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/somepage.html' # <-- Replace this with the URL of the page you're trying to post to.
values = {'990' : 'comment here'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

## You can optionally print the response like so:
the_page = response.read()
print(the_page)
```

Comment: He's probably trying to write a client that can automate the posting.

Answer (score 1):

[Urllib2 - the missing manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for posting with forms in Python, or the ClientForm submodule. It allows you to make a virtual browser navigate to a page, and gives you access to the links and forms on the page. You can fill out a form and do "form.submit()" with ease. The site has several examples.